# Google Voice : Your phone number couldn't be verified

Tags: nexus-one, google-voice

After I sign in, i'm asked to set a voicemail PIN, and immediately after that i get the error:

> Your phone number could not be verified. Please try again.

How do I verify my phone for Google Voice usage on my Android?

Note: I'm using `Nexus one` with the latest 2.3.6 update. I'm not a US citizen. And I can make calls from my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you're not a US citizen, but do you live in the US and have a US phone number? If not, Google voice is not yet available outside US, and you just have to wait for them to expand the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have GVoice via other means, then the app should pick up the saved phone number from the web service.  Don't try to use your non-US number (see onik's answer).

If you *do* have a US number, try to activate via the website instead of the app.

Answer (score 0):

There are [some](http://www.how-to-hide-ip.info/2009/08/04/activate-google-voice-account-from-outside-usa/) [guides](http://www.labnol.org/internet/get-google-voice-phone-number/18425/) [online](http://www.google.com/webhp?#q=google%20voice%20outside%20us) about activating a non-US phone number on Google Voice.  It usually requires [acquiring of a US phone number](http://www.labnol.org/software/get-usa-local-phone-number/18407/), and installation of IP-spoofing software on your PC.

Comment: Is it a one time setup, and once I activated it I will be able to use it? Or I will have to use IP spoofing on my android as well?

Comment: I'm not sure as I haven't tested this myself, but from the instructions it looks like you only need to spoof the IP address for the verification step.